# Explanation of PostgreSQL Query

Tags: sql, database, postgresql, relational-database

I'm having trouble unpacking this postgreSQL query:

```
   select name, revenue from (
    select facs.name, sum(case 
                when memid = 0 then slots * facs.guestcost
                else slots * membercost
            end) as revenue
        from cd.bookings bks
        inner join cd.facilities facs
            on bks.facid = facs.facid
        group by facs.name
    ) as agg where revenue < 1000
order by revenue;
```

Here are my questions.

1. the outer query is pulling "revenue" from the table returned by the inner query, which has a column name "revenue" as well. Is the outer query simply pulling the column from the inner query with this reference?
2. what is "as agg" doing in this query? It isn't referenced anywhere.

Answer (score 1):

1. Yes. The outer query just references the value of "revenue" of the inner query which, in this case, is the result of the sum() function.
2. It's an alias for the result. If, for any reason, you want to use the result of your outer query, in another query, you reference it as 'agg'. For example, lets say I want to get the revenue < 500 of the initial result, I would create the following query:

   SELECT revenue FROM agg WHERE revenue < 500

Comment: Glad I could help!

Comment: To use the results from the outer query, you would have to assign its generated result a new alias.

SELECT revenue FROM (
     select name, revenue from (.......
     .......
     order by revenue; 
) as rev
WHERE revenue < 500

Answer (score 0):

The inner query is querying the table 'bookings' (and naming it bks) it is joining the table 'facilities' (and naming it facs). The join is occurring on bookings.facid being equal to facilities.facid

The generated results of that join are being called "agg".  There must be multiple entries with the same name in the 'facilities', as the results are grouped by facilities.'name'.   'revenue' is being calculated by the sum() function, which is calculating a total using all of the entries consisting of the same 'facilities'.'name'

"agg" is the name given to the results of inner query, as all generated results must be named, but does not need to be referenced in the outer query because 'name' and 'revenue' are unique in the outer query. So, "SELECT name, revenue"  is the same as "SELECT agg.name, agg.revenue"

Answer (score 0):

Read it like this

There is inner query which fetches you two columns name and revenew from joins

Below part is your `revenew` from `bookings` table

`sum(case when memid = 0 then slots * facs.guestcost else slots * membercost  end) as revenue`

The `booking` table is then joined with `facilities` table  like this
`inner join cd.facilities facs  on bks.facid = facs.facid`

Since this is inner query so alias is must to give like `agg`

after when the inner query returns the data , the main select  query
`select name, revenue` extracts the data `<1000`

1. the outer query is pulling "revenue" from the table returned by the inner query, which has a column name "revenue" as well. Is the outer query simply pulling the column from the inner query with this reference?
   YES
2. what is "as agg" doing in this query? It isn't referenced anywhere.

   its just an alias to tag that from as a table.